# Can we perform matrix operations of CNOT on 2 qubit systems?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

I am trying to get started on quantum computing. I find that 2x2 matrices like Pauli X,Y,Z,or gates like H,S can be used to perform operations on single qubits as direct matrix multiplication. For e.g
    X*q0 or H*q1 etc

However, I am not sure, how I can apply the CNOT matrix represented as $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\  0& 0 &  0&1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$
to perform operation on 2 bit qubits for e.g |00> or |01>. How can we determine the result through matrix operations, though the explanation is itself easy.

It is easy to say that we flip the target qubit if the control qubit is 1
as below for the following CNOT operations on qubits |00> or |01>

```
  CNOT|00> -> |00>
  CNOT|10> -> |11>
```

**How can we use the matrix operations to prove this?**

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basis states are represented as four-dimensional vectors, like so:

\begin{align}
|00\rangle&=[1, 0, 0, 0]^T \\
|01\rangle&=[0, 1, 0, 0]^T \\
|10\rangle&=[0, 0, 1, 0]^T \\
|11\rangle&=[0, 0, 0, 1]^T
\end{align}

You then simply apply the matrix transformation to these vectors.

For example, a quantum state may be expanded as a linear combination of this basis:

$$ |\psi\rangle= a|00\rangle + b|01\rangle + c|10\rangle + d|11\rangle $$

The CNOT matrix may then be applied:

\begin{align}
\mathrm{CNOT}\cdot|\psi\rangle &= \mathrm{CNOT}\cdot(a|00\rangle + b|01\rangle + c|10\rangle + d|11\rangle) \\
&=a\cdot\mathrm{CNOT}\cdot|00\rangle + ... + d\cdot\mathrm{CNOT}\cdot|11\rangle
\end{align}

where you perform standard matrix multiplication on the basis vectors to get:

$$ \mathrm{CNOT}\cdot|\psi\rangle = a|00\rangle+b|01\rangle + c|11\rangle + d|10\rangle $$

In other words, the CNOT gate has transformed $|10\rangle\mapsto|11\rangle$ and $|11\rangle\mapsto|10\rangle$.